# Can't do a git pull

Tags: git

I'm trying to do a **git pull** and get the error message:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
<myFileName>
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
```

So, I try to remove the file using the command **git rm --cache**  which results in the error:

```
fatal: pathspec
<myFileName>
did not match any files
```

At this point I'm stuck.  I can't pull until I remove the file.  But, it tells me I can't remove the file.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have untracked files in the way of the pull.  You can't remove them with `git rm --cached` because they are untracked.  They don't appear in the index.  You need to remove them with plain old `rm`

Answer (score 115):

This is an opportunity for the 'git clean' command. **If you don't care about the untracked files** ... `git clean -n` to see what will be removed, and `git clean -f` to go ahead and rm untracked files.

Add -d to the commands to also operate on directories:

```
  git clean -dn
  git clean -df
```

Comment: It really helped me. :)

Comment: This is certainly helpful, but is there a way to just let git overwrite the files? I have some files I'd rather keep that have nothing to do with the collision, and I don't want to manually go and find the offending files to remove them just so they can be replaced. Surely there should be a "force pull" option or something?

Comment: You might want to reset your branch. I'm sure others can explain this more crisply, but consider `git reset --hard branch_name`. There are variants to that command, but that is basically what you are after. One tip - make sure you accurately specify the branch name you mean. For example, in the situation that prompted this question, local branch `X` is distinct from remote branch `origin/X`, so the command will probably look something like `git reset --hard origin/my_branch`. That tells your local git index to "discard everything going on and reset to HEAD of origin/my_branch".

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

That file isn't in the current branch yet, so you can't remove it with `git rm --cache`. Just use `rm`.

Comment: It would be preferable to just move the current file, in the case of there were modifications in this file.

So, use the simple console command mv to move the file or rm if you want to erase that file.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with other posters, the issue is that the file isn't being tracked by git.  the command `git rm` works on files being tracked.  rm will remove the file from your machine.  Alternatively you could add the file to your list of ignored files, or file types if that is convenient.  You could also use one of the GUI tools like tortoise git to quickly delete all untracked files.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the original error message, that file is *untracked*.  That means `git` doesn't know anything about it.  Just remove it from the filesystem using `rm`.  If you care about the contents, just move it somewhere else.